# Defining the server to use in openapi-generator.tech Go client

Tags: swagger, openapi-generator

Working on a new SDK generated from openapi-generator.tech, using the Go client templates.

I have the following being generated for my configuration:

```
func NewConfiguration() *Configuration {
cfg := &Configuration{
    DefaultHeader:    make(map[string]string),
    UserAgent:        "OpenAPI-Generator/3.0.0/go",
    Debug:            false,
    Servers:          ServerConfigurations{
        {
            URL: "https://{subdomain}.{domain}",
            Description: "No description provided",
            Variables: map[string]ServerVariable{
                "subdomain": ServerVariable{
                    Description: "The subdomain of your organization",
                    DefaultValue: "your-subdomain",
                },
                "domain": ServerVariable{
                    Description: "The domain of your organization.",
                    DefaultValue: "example.com",
                    EnumValues: []string{
                        "example.com",
                        "preview.com",
                        "example-emea.com",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        {
            URL: "https://{customDomain}",
            Description: "No description provided",
            Variables: map[string]ServerVariable{
                "customDomain": ServerVariable{
                    Description: "The custom domain configured for your organization",
                    DefaultValue: "auth.your-custom-domain.com",
                },
            },
        },
    },
    OperationServers: map[string]ServerConfigurations{
    },
}
return cfg
}
```

My question is with the following setup:

```
ctx := context.WithValue(
        context.Background(),
        ContextAPIKeys,
        APIKey{
            Key:    "abcd1234",
            Prefix: "TOKEN",
        },
    )

    cfg := NewConfiguration()

    client := NewAPIClient(cfg)

    appReq := client.ApplicationApi.CreateApplication(ctx)
    appReq.application = &NewOpenIdConnectApplication().Application
    app, resp, err := client.ApplicationApi.CreateApplicationExecute(appReq)
```

How would I go about setting the subdomain to my custom subdomain, or even telling the client to use my "custom domain"

This is important for me to understand so I can tell my customer via README how to do it.  Currently when making the API calls, it is using `https://your-subdomain.example.com`

Answer (score 1):

So, it appears that you can just do

```golang
configuration := NewConfiguration()
configuration.Host = "mycustom.domain.com"
```

Not sure if there is a better way or not.

Comment: That should be helpful, I'll try that too as I was looking for something similar. Feels like there should be a way to pick one of the pre-defined servers. No idea how to do that yet though.